# Getting the ids back in order in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a test blog app that has various posts and comments . While following the tutorial we created several posts and comments associated with it and each got associated with a unique id.

so I could call some_address/posts/1 or /2 or 3 and each had a destroy option.

I deleted the post with id 1 and now as expected it gives me an error when I try going for posts/1 . But this has made my application look ugly and inconsistent.

I know I cannot get back that content and id restored . But is there a code I can put to update the /2 and /3 to become /1 and /2 ?

I am a novice and just testing it . Please help

Comment: What do you aim for? A nice 404 (not found) error page (something I would expect if an record was removed)? Or redirecting the user to an other post (what might be a valid option)?

Comment: So what I understand is that I can only display a more user friendly message with 404 .... But not update the post ids such that post 2 becomes post 1 and post 3 becomes post 2 ? Or can I add a code which gives me an option to assign a post id . So that I can again create the missing post ? Basically I won't like my code to look broken

Comment: Are you aware that the error page you see in development is not the same page an user would see in production?

Comment: To change the `id` is bad idea. It's better to show that 404 error Or Data not available. You must use `dependent destroy` so when data is deleted it's references also removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should not change `id` in the database once you saved a record. You will run in all kinds of problems (broken foreign keys and references) if you try.

If you do not like to show a 404 (not found) error page to the user if an post doesn't exist, you could try to redirect the user to the next post like this:

```
# in your controller
def show
  @post = Post.where(id: params[:id]).first

  redirect_to(Post.where('id > ?', params[:id]).first!) unless @post
end
```

Note that this code will still show a 404 (not found) if there is no newer post than the one that was deleted.

Comment: This is definitely a much better approach than updating all of your post ids.

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all use this line in your post model

```
 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

2) Use 404 Error page on non existing pages, like in your case post does not exist any more.